# Contar letras sin tener en cuenta los espacios

Tags: python

Hola buenos días como puedo hacer para que este programa me pueda contar la cantidad de letras sin contar los espacios?

> Escribir un programa que pregunte el nombre del usuario en consola, el programa debe mostrar el mensaje “(nombre) tiene (n) letras”,
> donde (nombre) es el nombre del usuario y (n) es el número de letras que tiene el nombre.

Lo que tengo por ahora:

```
nombre = input("Ingrese su nombre: ")

print("El nombre {}, tiene {} letras".format(nombre,len(nombre)))
```

Comment: puedes utilizar el metodo `strip` de python.

Comment: no lo conozco como seria asi?

Comment: o podrías simplemente: print("El nombre {}, tiene {} letras".format(nombre,len(nombre)-nombre.count(" "))) donde solo restas la cantidad de espacios que haya

Answer (score 4):

Para "eliminar" de la cuenta de caracteres los espacios, hay algunas posibilidades:

1. Comprensión de listas: construimos al vuelo una lista con todos los caracteres menos los espacios

   ```
   len([c for c in nombre if c != " "])
   ```
2. Eliminamos los espacios antes de contar:

   ```
   len(nombre.replace(" ", ""))
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Con expresiones regulares:

```
import re

nombre = input("Ingrese su nombre: ").strip()
espacios = ''.join(re.findall("\s+", nombre))
print("El nombre {}, tiene {} letras".format(nombre, len(nombre) - len(espacios)))
```

La expresión regular `s+` calza con todos los espacios en el nombre.

`re.findall` encuentra todas las ocurrencias de espacios dentro del nombre, retornando una lista con los diversos espacios encontrados. Usando `join` colapsamos la lista en una cadena.

Entonces, `len(nombre)` me da el largo total, y `len(espacios)` me da el largo de los espacios.

#### Demo

```
Ingrese su nombre: José   Ramón  Perez
El nombre José   Ramón  Perez, tiene 14 letras

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Perdon si ofendo, no es mi intención, es más por curiosidad. Pero por que utilizar el modulo re para lograr eso?

Comment: Simplemente por jugar, por inventar otra forma absurda de lograr algo simple.

Comment: Ya veo! Aparte, uno puede aprender un poco de regexp haciendolo de ese modo c:

Comment: Tú lo has dicho.

Comment: una adaptación con re de mi comentario,

Comment: @tincopasan. Perdoname. Soy atolondrado y me lanzo a contestar sin leer comentarios ni otras respuestas. Luego que lo mencionaste, leí tu comentario y veo que ambos hacemos una resta. ¿Debería eliminar mi respuesta?

Comment: Yo al menos considero que tu respuesta ofrece una forma diferente a las otras respuestas y al comentario de Tincopasan. Yo la dejaría c:

Answer (score 0):

Hola otra manera para que solo les las letras:

```
nombre = input("Ingrese su nombre: ")
nombre=nombre.lower()
count=0
for i in nombre:
  if i in 'abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz':
      count+=1
print("El nombre {}, tiene {} letras".format(nombre,count))
```

Comment: Espero que te sirva

Comment: recuerda que si haces un salto de linea habiendo abierto comillas `"", ''` es una sintaxis inválida, también ten cuidado con la indentación

Answer (score 0):

- Puedes contar la longitud de la cadena y restarle el número de espacios:

```
len(s) - s.count(' ')
```

- O sumar la longitud de todas las palabras que contiene:

```
sum(len(x) for x in s.split())
```

---

Probémoslo:

```
def cuenta_letras(cadena: str):
    print(f'"{cadena}" tiene {sum(len(x) for x in cadena.split())} letras')
    print(f'"{cadena}" tiene {len(cadena) - cadena.count(" ")} letras')

for cadena in ["hola qué tal", "    bien    "]:
    cuenta_letras(cadena)
```

Devuelve:

```
"hola qué tal" tiene 10 letras
"hola qué tal" tiene 10 letras
"    bien    " tiene 4 letras
"    bien    " tiene 4 letras
```

Answer (score -1):

Puedes hacerlo con el método [`strip()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_strip.asp) si deseas eliminar al principio y al final.

```
nombre = input("Ingrese su nombre: ")

print("El nombre {}, tiene {} letras".format(nombre,len(nombre.strip())))
```

o puedes utilizar `split()`  y `.join` ejemplo

```
nombre = input("Ingrese su nombre: ")

print("El nombre {}, tiene {} letras".format(nombre,len(' '.join(nombre.split()))))
```

Comment: ok muchisimas gracias

Comment: @MatiasB recuerda que, si la respuesta te sirvió, puedes marcarla como aceptada para que otros sepan que es la solución

Comment: Tener en cuenta que `strip()` solo elimina espacios al comienzo y al final de la cadena

Comment: Ese código no hace lo que crees. Es recomendable probar antes de publicar.

Answer (score -1):

```
a=input("ingrese un numero")
contador=0
for x in a:
    
    if x != " ":
        contador+=1
        h=contador
if h==1:
    print ("unidad")
elif h==2:
    print ("decena")
elif h==3:
    print ("centena")
elif h==4:
    print ("unidad de mil")
elif h==5:
    print ("decenas de mil")
elif h==6:
    print ("centenas de mil")
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).